# ПРОБЛЕМА С ЗАВИСАНИЕМ ИНТЕРФЕЙСА PYQT5 || НУЖНА ПОМОЩЬ

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5

Всем добрый вечер. Столкнулся с проблемой, что мой интерфейс при запуске задачи зависает до того момента, как задача не пройдет. Я прочитал много статей и знаю, что нужно сделать многопоточность. Проблема лишь в том, что просидел около 3 часов и не могу корректно запустить программу. Можете ли вы посоветовать что-либо в коде программы(я только неделю сижу на питоне)
`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import resourcen_rc
from design import Ui_MainWindow
from info import Ui_Info
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard as key
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
ui.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Клавиша запуска: ')
ui.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText('Клавиша паузы:')
ui.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText('Клавиша чата: ')

def connect_slider_spinbox() -> None:
    ui.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(ui.spinBox.setValue)
    ui.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(ui.horizontalSlider.setValue)
    ui.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(Value)
    
def Value():
    values = ui.spinBox.value()
    ui.label.setText(str(values) + ' seconds')

connect_slider_spinbox()
Value()

def method():
    on = ui.lineEdit.text()
    pause = ui.lineEdit_2.text()
    chat = ui.lineEdit_3.text()
    times = ui.spinBox.value()
    x = 1000
    try:
        if chat == "":
            while True:
                if key.is_pressed(str(on)):
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    while x > 7:
                        pyautogui.write(f"{x} - 7 = {x-7}")
                        pyautogui.press('enter')
                        time.sleep(times)
                        x -= 7
                        if key.is_pressed(str(pause)):
                            break
                    if key.is_pressed(str(pause)):
                        break
        else:
            while True:
                if key.is_pressed(str(on)):
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    while x > 7:
                        pyautogui.press(str(chat))
                        pyautogui.write(f"{x} - 7 = {x-7}")
                        pyautogui.press('enter')
                        time.sleep(times)
                        x -= 7
                        if key.is_pressed(str(pause)):
                            break
                    if key.is_pressed(str(pause)):
                        break
    except:
        pass
ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(method)
            
def openInfo():
    global MainWindows
    global uis
    MainWindows = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    uis = Ui_Info()
    uis.setupUi(MainWindows)
    MainWindows.show()
    MainWindow.close()

    def returnback():
        MainWindow.show()
        MainWindows.close()

    uis.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(returnback)
    
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(openInfo)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я извиняюсь, что тупой и ничего не понимаю. Однако, без многопоточности программа работает корректно

Comment: Здесь минимум несколько десятков примеров с PyQt5.QtCore.QThread, посмотрите их и поймёте что не так с вашим "кодом".

Comment: P.S. я начал вопросы задавать только после освоения синтаксиса и некоторых паттернов программирования. Это около 3-х лет изучения языка Python, самостоятельно. Вы что хотите при одном исправлении кода задавать новый вопрос? Вас просто будут игнорировать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. 
Опубликуйте модули `design.py` и `info.py`. 
Напишитк лучше, что вы хотите сделать. 
Какие действия надо сделать чтобы получить то, что вы хотите сделать. 
Нельзя использовать `time.sleep()` и `while True` в основном потоке 
приложения, т.к. это замораживает интерфейс. 
Глобальные переменные - это зло.